# NSArray becoming invalid after assignment

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsarray

This is a strange problem, but two of my NSArrays are becoming invalid right after assignment. I went into debug and verified this during assignment. The screenshot shows it all. I must be missing a silly error somewhere - can someone please help!

[Link to Screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/217/screenshoterror.png)

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the `-retain` message to the array on assignment, like this:

```
ivar = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", nil] retain];
```

The reason why they are going out of scope is because `-arrayWithObjects:` returns an autoreleased object. It is for this reason that you must send it the `-retain` message.

Also, don't forget to `-release` these objects in your `-dealloc` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use -retain- dude. This will solve your problem.